# To find the area between the curves $y=e^{x^2}$ and $y=\sin(x+1)+2$

Tags: integration

I needed to find the area between the curves $y=e^{x^2}$ and $y=\sin(x+1)+2$. So to find bounds for $x$, I need to find values of $x$, where these two curves intersect. But I don't know how to solve such equation i.e. $e^{x^2}=\sin(x+1)+2$. I took help of graphing app to find them. I got values as -0.8696 and 1.0312. Also I will need to find integral with integrand $e^{x^2}$, which looks worrying. Do I have to take help of online integral calculator to evaluate that? Any hint or start will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I think you cannot solve analitically. You need numerical methods.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @TitoEliatron

Comment: Numerically I got $\approx 2.54$ sq. units